# How to change color of painted bitmaps on canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am new to android and i have an app that does painting on canvas. After painting on canvas i am saving the bitmaps as png format image and it works.

The painting is done using green color but before saving i want to change the color of green painted bitmaps, how to change the color of green to white color.

An example would be like this

On painting : (the image is set as background i.e MyView.setbackgroud(sample.png))

[image: during painting]

On Saving: (the result after saving the image )

[image: saved image]

The result that i want is like this which will be saved in png format.

[image: resultant image]

```
       FileOutputStream ostream = null;
    try
    {
        ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        System.out.println(ostream);
        View targetView = mv;

        // myDrawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        //   Bitmap save = Bitmap.createBitmap(myDrawView.getDrawingCache());
        //   myDrawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        // copy this bitmap otherwise distroying the cache will destroy
        // the bitmap for the referencing drawable and you'll not
        // get the captured view
        //   Bitmap save = b1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
        //BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(b);
        //canvasView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        //   myDrawView.destroyDrawingCache();
        // Bitmap save = myDrawView.getBitmapFromMemCache("0");
        // myDrawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        //Bitmap save = myDrawView.getDrawingCache(false);




        Bitmap well = mv.mBitmap;
        Bitmap save = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //Paint paint2 = new Paint();
       // paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        Canvas now = new Canvas(save);
        now.drawRect(new Rect(0,0,320,480), paint);
        now.drawBitmap(well, new Rect(0,0,well.getWidth(),well.getHeight()), new Rect(0,0,320,480),null);
       // now.drawBitmap(well,well.getWidth(),well.getHeight(),paint2);
      //  now.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorBlack));
      //  now.drawBitmap(well,0,paint2,well.getWidth(),well.getHeight());

        if(save == null) {
            System.out.println("NULL bitmap save\n");
        }
        save.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        //ostream.flush();
        //ostream.close();
    }catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IO error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: i dont know if i am asking the wrong question but i just want the color to be changed from green and black to white and black, how to do this. any help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Color.black`, use `Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0);`

```
ARGB = Alpha, Red, Green, Blue.
```

Comment: it does not work instead of changing the green color to white it changes the black to light green on color.argb(255,0,255,0);

Comment: the painted strokes are green which i want as white

Comment: Green would be 255, 0, 255, 0 ... zero red, all green, zero blue

Comment: in second picture the paint is done using green color and that i want to change to white color and on giving Color 255,0,255,0 it does not change the painted region but the canvas black background changes to green.

Comment: i am using canvas color for background so on changing color the background color changes not the strokes color that i did earlier.

Comment: only paint color i want  to change where strokes are made by touch.